# How to get the last level vertices of a particular vertex where last level value is not known using gremlinPipeLine

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I want to write a query to find all the vertices at last level of a particular vertex where the value of last level  is unknown using **Gremlin**.
Suppose I have a vertex `A`. The next set of vertices that are connected to `A` are [B,C,D]. Vertices at 2nd level [E,F,G] , and so on .

Comment: Good that you want something, but what do you want from us?

Comment: What do you mean with 'last level of a particular vertex'? Give an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would give you all the leaves of what I assume is a tree structure:

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object.outE.hasNext()}
```

The above should traverse you out from vertex "1" until you reach the "last level" of any particular path.  The vertices emitted should be whatever this traversal finds at termination.

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> v1 = g.addVertex()
==>v[0]
gremlin> v2 = g.addVertex()
==>v[1]
gremlin> v3a = g.addVertex()
==>v[2]
gremlin> v3b = g.addVertex()
==>v[3]
gremlin> v4 = g.addVertex() 
==>v[4]
gremlin> v1.addEdge('next',v2)
==>e[5][0-next->1]
gremlin> v2.addEdge('next',v3a)
==>e[6][1-next->2]
gremlin> v2.addEdge('next',v3b)
==>e[7][1-next->3]
gremlin> v3a.addEdge('next',v4)
==>e[8][2-next->4]                 
gremlin> g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object.outE.hasNext()}
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
```

Note that this can be a dangerous traversal if you aren't sure of your data structure, as it could simply loop forever if the graph cycles.

As a side note, you can control the emission of intermediate vertices (not just the final ones) by adding another closure (i.e. the emit closure).  For example,

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){true}{true}
```

The above will loop to end and emit every vertex it finds.

Finding the "height" of the tree could be done by grabbing the max of loops:

```
gremlin> h=0;g.v(1).out.loop(1){h=Math.max(h,it.loops);it.object.outE.hasNext()}
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
gremlin> h
==>3
```

Comment: Hi @stephen mallette . thanks for the quick reply . The first query is not producing any results .Though the second query is working fine . I would also want to know how to find the height of a tree.